# Discord.py, buttons on message dont work after bot restarts

Tags: discord, discord.py

The buttons work after the command is sent, they show up on the embed, but once the bot restarts and I press the button that was on the previous embed, the discord app gives me an error that says `interaction failed`, here's the discord.py code.

```py
async def ticket(ctx, *title):
    button = Button(label="Ready to start buying?",
                    style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    guild = ctx.guild
    dropperrole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=1003171723207774218)
    topdropperrole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=1004989656137465917)

    title = list(title)
    title = " ".join(map(str, title))

    view = View()
    view.add_item(button)

    async def button_callback(interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Creating channel...",
                                                ephemeral=True)
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await interaction.edit_original_message(
            content=
            f"Channel successfully created #ticket-{(interaction.user.name).lower()} !"

        )
        overwrites = {
            guild.default_role:
            discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False),
            interaction.user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True),
            guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True),
            dropperrole: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True),
            topdropperrole: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True)
        }
      
        chan = await ticket_category.create_text_channel(
            f"ticket-{(interaction.user.name).lower()}", overwrites=overwrites)
        id = discord.utils.get(
            ctx.guild.channels,
            name=f"ticket-{(interaction.user.name).lower()}")
        await interaction.edit_original_message(
            content=f"Channel successfully created {id.mention}!")

        ccEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f"Hello {interaction.user.name}!",
         
                                color=0x2ecc71)      
        ccEmbed.add_field(
            name="Ready to buy?",
            value="Type `$dhc` to buy DHC, or `$buygen` to buy Gen! type `$fastpass` to buy fastpass, this allows you to skip all orders! To view prices, type `$prices`!",
            inline=True)
        ccEmbed.set_footer(text="discord.gg/dhcc | Rvse's Gen")

        await chan.send(embed=ccEmbed)

    button.callback = button_callback
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup persistence so the bot will restart the view of your button when it launches. I think your are using Rapptz discord library? If so here is an example you can checkout:
https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/persistent.py

Comment: Hey there SMC! As a rule, please try to avoid just posting links, as they have a tendency to break, or not load for users with slow internet. If possible, try to extract the referenced information and put it in your answer.